# Proper format for drawing polygon data in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've tried this different ways, but nothing seems to be working. Here is what I currently have:

```
var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
         .attr("width", 1000)
         .attr("height", 667),

 scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([-30,30])
        .range([0,600]),

scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,50])
        .range([500,0]),

poly = [{"x":0, "y":25},
        {"x":8.5,"y":23.4},
        {"x":13.0,"y":21.0},
        {"x":19.0,"y":15.5}];

vis.selectAll("polygon")
    .data(poly)
    .enter()
    .append("polygon")
    .attr("points",function(d) { 
        return [scaleX(d.x),scaleY(d.y)].join(",")})
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width",2);
```

I assume the problem here is either with the way I am defining the points data as an array of individual point objects, or something to do with how I'm writing the function for the `.attr("points",...`

I've been looking all over the web for a tutorial or example of how to draw a simple polygon, but I just can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A polygon looks something like: `<polygon points="200,10 250,190 160,210" />`

So, your full poly array should produce one long string that will create one polygon. Because we are talking about one polygon the data join should also be an array with only one element. That is why the code below shows: `data([poly])` if you wanted two identical polygons you would change this to `data([poly, poly])`.

The goal is to create one string from your array with 4 objects. I used a `map` and another `join` for this:

```
poly = [{"x":0.0, "y":25.0},
        {"x":8.5,"y":23.4},
        {"x":13.0,"y":21.0},
        {"x":19.0,"y":15.5}];

vis.selectAll("polygon")
    .data([poly])
  .enter().append("polygon")
    .attr("points",function(d) { 
        return d.map(function(d) {
            return [scaleX(d.x),scaleY(d.y)].join(",");
        }).join(" ");
    })
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width",2);
```

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4xXQT/

Comment: Thanks! I need to study it, but obviously this solution works. Do you think this is the best way to do a polygon? It just strikes me as a bit clunky to have that function within a function construct. But maybe that's how it needs to be? I guess my questions is should I construct the data object in this way, or maybe there is a better/cleaner way to do it.

Comment: To give you some more ideas: If the original data would have been a 2D array with scaled datapoints like [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]], then the points function would be much simpler: function(d) { return d.join(" "); }. This relies on the fact that Javascript's default toString for an array is to join them with a comma. For example console.log("" + [0,1,2]); would print "0,1,2".

Comment: See also D3 group discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/BowNx0g9bZY/KGnmsXQcn4AJ

Comment: nautat, that's exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 10):

The above answers are needlessly complicated.

All you have to do is specify the points as a string and everything works fine. Something like this below will work.

```
var canvas = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("height", 600)
   .attr("width", 600);

canvas.append("polygon")
   .attr("points", "200,10 250,190 160,210")
   .style("fill", "green")
   .style("stroke", "black")
   .style("strokeWidth", "10px");
```

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to draw polygon shapes? - like this. http://bl.ocks.org/2271944 The start of your code looks like a typical chart - which would usually conclude something like this.

```
chart.selectAll("line")
     .data(x.ticks(10))
   .enter().append("line")
     .attr("x1", x)
     .attr("x2", x)
     .attr("y1", 0)
     .attr("y2", 120)
.style("stroke", "#ccc");
```

Comment: this is not a polygon, it is conncted lines.