# Process multiple polygons d3

Tags: d3.js

The answer below on drawing a polygon works well for a single polygon. However, what if there are more than one polygon? Simply adding an additional polygon with points seems not to work even though using "select all" would seem to indicate that it would be OK to add a couple more polygons without much problem..

We have an array of polygons, each of which has an attribute Points which is an array of points.

The first array with polygon should obviously be mapped and the point arrays of each member processed as described. But how to spedify this two-level structure with d3?

[Proper format for drawing polygon data in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204562/proper-format-for-drawing-polygon-data-in-d3)

Comment: What exactly isn't working for you? I can add a second polygon without problems, see http://jsfiddle.net/4xXQT/52/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff You should publish this as an answer. I don't see what's wrong with your code either.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple and straightaway. Just pass the array of polygons as data to d3 selection.
In your case it seems that you are using an array of polygons which are composite objects, each having a key called 'Points'. I assume it looks something like this-

```
var arrayOfPolygons =  [{
    "name": "polygon 1",
    "points":[
      {"x":0.0, "y":25.0},
      {"x":8.5,"y":23.4},
      {"x":13.0,"y":21.0},
      {"x":19.0,"y":15.5}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "polygon 2",
    "points":[
      {"x":0.0, "y":50.0},
      {"x":15.5,"y":23.4},
      {"x":18.0,"y":30.0},
      {"x":20.0,"y":16.5}
    ]
  },
  ... etc.
];
```

You will just have to use `d.Points` instead of `d` when writing the equivalent map function, which can be written as follows-

```
vis.selectAll("polygon")
  .data(arrayOfPolygons)
  .enter().append("polygon")
  .attr("points",function(d) { 
    return d.points.map(function(d) { 
      return [scaleX(d.x),scale(d.y)].join(",");
    }).join(" ");
  })
  .attr("stroke","black")
  .attr("stroke-width",2);
```

You can check the following working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunkjn/xubZf/) to verify.

**EDIT-** The same example as above with convex hull implementation for rendering complete polygons. http://jsfiddle.net/arunkjn/EpBCH/1/ Note the difference in polygon#4

Comment: Your jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/2zF9J/) shows an example with a single 4-vertex polygon. Perhaps you pasted the wrong link?

Comment: @CharlBotha I have updated the Jsfiddle link in the answer. Sorry for the wrong link before.

Comment: Can we add tooltip also in this example ?