# d3js/svg - Polygon without fixed coordinates?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Is it possible to create an SVG polygon shape in d3js without hard coding the coordinates?

From what I understand a most common way to create an SVG polygon shape is to hard code the coordinates like done in the below linked examples. 
[Process multiple polygons d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939325/process-multiple-polygons-d3)

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#PolygonElement

But I do not want to hard code the coordinates since I want to use a force directed layout algorithm (in d3js) to define the coordinates like done in the below linked example.
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2706022

Thanks,
Erno Lindfors

Comment: You can use exactly the same approach as in the example you've linked to.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

Actually I have been using the example given in http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2706022. 
In this example they are using circles but I would like to use polygons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13204818/1651713

It works fine with a force layout, e.g.

```
var polygon = svg.selectAll('polygon')
  .data([nodes])
  .enter()
  .append('polygon')
  .style('fill', 'green');

force.on('tick', function() {
  polygon.attr('points',function(d){
    return d.map(function(d) {
      return [d.x,d.y].join(',');
    }).join(' ');
  });
});
```