# d3js/svg - Polygon without fixed coordinates - Suggested solution does not work?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I was recently asking how to create an SVG pologyn without fixed coordinates in this group and stringman5 kindly gave hints to solve the problem, see the full discussion in [d3js/svg - Polygon without fixed coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276237/d3js-svg-polygon-without-fixed-coordinates/29281507#29281507).

I have included the solution stringman5 suggested in my implementation I am now getting an error in JavaScript console.

I have included all codes I am using in the end of this message along with an input edge example I have given in html.textarea.

Below is the exact error message I am getting.

```
Uncaught TypeError:  PolygonTest.js: 88
undefined is not a function
```

Any idea why this error happens?

Thanks,
Erno

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>Polygon Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PolygonTest.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td><div id="svgContent"></div></td></tr>
            <tr><th align="left">Give edges</th></tr>
            <tr><td><textarea id="edgeFile" cols=30 rows=20></textarea></td></tr>
            <tr><td><button type="button" onclick="constNet()">Construct Network</button></td></tr>
        </table>  
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="PolygonTest.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PolygonTest.css

```
line {
    stroke: #000000; /* Black */
    stroke-width: 1;
}
text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

PolygonTest.js

```
function constNet() {
    var edgeRows = document.getElementById("edgeFile").value.split("\n");
    var nodeIdIntIds = {};
    var nodes = [];
    var edges = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < edgeRows.length; i++) {
    var row = edgeRows[i];
    var cols = row.split("\t");
    var sNodeId = cols[0].trim();
    var tNodeId = cols[1].trim();
    var sNodeIntId;
    if (!nodeIdIntIds.hasOwnProperty(sNodeId)) {
        sNodeIntId = Object.keys(nodeIdIntIds).length;
        var sNode = {name: sNodeId, id:sNodeIntId, fixed:false};
        nodes[nodes.length] = sNode;
        nodeIdIntIds[sNodeId] = true;
    }
    var tNodeIntId;
    if (!nodeIdIntIds.hasOwnProperty(tNodeId)) {
        tNodeIntId = Object.keys(nodeIdIntIds).length;
        var tNode = {name: tNodeId, id:tNodeIntId, fixed:false};
        nodes[nodes.length] = tNode;
        nodeIdIntIds[tNodeId] = true;
    }
    edges[edges.length] = {source:sNodeIntId, target:tNodeIntId};
}

var WIDTH = 2000;
var HEIGHT = 2000;
var svg = d3.select("#svgContent")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", WIDTH)
    .attr("height", HEIGHT)
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin slice') 
    .append('g');

var dataSet = {nodes: nodes, edges: edges};

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(dataSet.nodes)
    .links(dataSet.edges)
    .size([WIDTH,HEIGHT])
    .linkStrength(0.1)
    .friction(0.9)
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(dataSet.edges)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

var node = svg.selectAll("polygon")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("polygon")
    .attr("fill", "#00ff00")    /* Green */
    .attr("stroke", "#ffffff")  /* White */
    .attr("stroke-width", "1.5px");

node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

function tick() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    node
        .attr(
            'points',
            function(d){
                return d.map(
                    function(d) {
                        return [d.x,d.y].join(',');
                    }
                ).join(' ');
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Input edge example:

```
1    2
3    4
1    4
2    5
6    1
1    5
2    1
5    1
2    1
7    9
8    1
8    2
1    3
10    5
6    7
11    6
8    5
5    11
2    7
12    5
13    4
5    14
14    12
14    1
14    4
15    10
16    11
16    17
17    18
17    19
19    20
21    8
21    22
23    3
24    4
25    6
26    2
```

Comment: I'm sure it's not the actual problem, but there certainly are a lot of `function(d) {` references, some of which are nested.  That `line 88` reference appears to be `return d.map(` which could correspond to an undefined function call if `d` was undefined or did not have a `map` function inside it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!
You are right the error happens in return d.map. I also think it is somehow related to an undefined function call. After some googling I am getting an impression this type of inner looping tends to be bug-prone but in this specific case I do not see any other workaround. So, I think I will now put this issue aside and thus try to survive without polygons. Perhaps I will come back to this issue later if new ideas pop up.