# Integrating SVG shape with axis scaling in d3, based on positional count rather than hard dimensions

Tags: d3.js, scale, polygon

A seemingly fundamental question. I envisage a d3 graph comprising horizontal and vertical scales, with **filled** geometric shapes (for the main part closed polygons) such as ellipses, trapeziums and arcs defined as SVG paths and distributed more or less randomly on the scale grid.

While their positions can easily be linked to/changed by axis scaling, because SVG elements generally represented by static (predefined) path definitions, their **dimensions** would, as I see it, remain unchanged.

Moreover, as these objects are filled, I seem to have no alternative to path (as opposed to line or other) definitions.

While I could simply scale the SVG elements in a secondary (and effectively dumb) percentage or other resizing transformation, I would like to scale the SVG element shapes directly with the x and y axis scales in an entirely **integrated** solution.

This implies path definitions made not in absolute terms, but in terms of the underlying scale intervals (x and y grid).

The problem is how to preconstruct a valid path definition such that it can be built in d3. Implied are two separate selection/transformation operations, one for each axis.

While certainly promising, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204562/proper-format-for-drawing-polygon-data-in-d3) still relies on hard dimensions (d.x & d.y) rather than positional counts (d). I would very much welcome any already compliant (positional count only) examples, also where based on other approaches. In the meantime, I will hack around with the example in hand..

Comment: Have you considered using the scales to scale the container and set the `transform` attribute on it accordingly?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand. As soon as I move from count-based (d) to dependent transformations or factored/offset (d.x or d.y type) positioning, I envisage both flexibility and control being progressively lost. Scaling in one integrated approach seems -at least in theory- to lie at the heart of d3 thinking.

Motivations?

o modify the scale's range, modify the shape.
o I'd like (later) to introduce further selections while avoiding unnecessary complexity. 

o scaling would affect not ALL symbol shapes, but only those connecting two or more elements.